# Is angular-token@6 compatible to angular@5 / ionic@3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, devise-token-auth, angular-token

I'm using the [ionic framework](https://ionicframework.com) in version 3. At time of writing, ionic 4 is still in beta. To [my understanding](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/upgrading-to-angular-6/131121), ionic 3 is only compatible up to [angular](http://angular.io) 5.

I'm trying to add [angular-token](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular-token), which currently is at 6.0.4. A version 5 of angular-token apparently does not exist.

When installing angular-token@6 together with angular@5 and ionic@3, I'm getting some strange errors like:

```
// angular-token.js:700
TypeError: Object is not a function.
(In 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__
["defineInjectable"])', 'Object' is an instance of Object)
```

From [similar issues](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/362) I suspect that angular-token might be incompatible to angular@5 and thus to ionic@3. Is this correct?

Could you recommend something to implement token-based authentication against [devise-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) with ionic 3?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is a good idea, yet, but I got it to work by gently updating some of the packages:

```
npm install angular-token --save
npm i @angular/common@6.0 @angular/core@6.0 -s
npm i rxjs@6.0 -s
npm i @angular/forms@6.0
npm i @angular/animations@6.0 @angular/platform-browser@6.0 @angular/http@6.0
npm i rxjs-compat@6.0 -s
npm i @angular/router@6.0 -s
```

From this, I would think that angular-token is not compatible to angular 5, but works with ionic 3 when updating some packages to angular 6. But, I've tested only `ionic lab`, no native environments, yet.